# How to configure Application side in WCF App for SSL connection with Pre Configured ADFS server?

Tags: c#, wcf, adfs, claims-based-identity, wif

I'm trying to configure my application so it authorises using ADFS server. I have configured ADFS server. In my Solution file(which is combination of WF, WPF projects and WCF) I have multiple no. of projects, I am using visual studio 2017. One project is client and another is server. Client is supposed to send authentication request to ADFS and receive token, which is sent to server side of my solution, where user is authorised to use application. Now my question is how do I configure it? Microsoft's documentations are using Identity and Access tool which is not supported in VS17. Is there any tutorial or legit guide/documentation which I can follow to configure my application.

Comment: Have you tried https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADDeveloperExperienceTeam.IdentityandAccessTool

Comment: Identity and Access tool only works with Visual Studio 2012, I tried installing it in different versions but it wouldn't let me.